# USB Debugging option on my Android keeps turning off

Tags: android, usb-debugging, motorola-droid

Every time I restart my Android phone after enabling the USB debugging in Developer Options, the USB Debugging option gets disabled.

How do I keep it enabled even after restarting my Android phone.

Comment: ah - i hadn't clicked that it was when the phone was restarted.  That's useful info thanks!

Comment: in future, won't buy an Honor/Huawei phone to avoid all this hassle

Answer (score 65):

This is an old issue but it seems that it still happens so I would like to share the solution that I have found.

I have the same issue with my Honor 9 Lite:

Every times I enable USB Debugging, I can see that, when I leave the developer menu and come back, USB debugging is OFF. I can't keep it ON.

I have found the solution on another web site and it is working for me:

- Disconnect the phone
- Revoke all the USB debugging permissions (on my phone, this option is proposed just after the USB Debugging switch)
- Enable USB Debugging
- Leave the developer menu
- Connect the phone to the PC
- Select 'transfer files' option
- Accept the PC certificate fingerprint.

Comment: The steps in this answer did not work for me. Using Huawei Honor 8 FRD-L04 with Android 7.0 Emui 5.0.4 operating system.

Comment: Perfectly worked for me on Huawei Y5 with Android 10.

Comment: I also clicked on Restore Defualt Settings and then it worked for me.

Comment: Works perfectly for me on Oppo A9 with Android 10 / ColorOS v7.1

Comment: @KaranSingh **THANK YOU! The posted answer did not work but your comment did. I had to go to the developer menu and click "Restore Default Settings" (the bar at the bottom of the developer menu), then I re-enabled developer menu and enabled USB debugging and then it worked!**

Answer (score 30):

I have found a solution on [XDA developpers forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/honor-9/help/usb-debugging-t3678521) for my Honor 7X, Android 8.0.0, EMUI 8.0.0, build BND-L21 8.0.0.302(C432log):

> Enable the 'allow debugging in charge only mode' and it should fix the problem

Note that it can already be enabled. You can try to disable and re-enable it to fix the problem.

Comment: In my case the mentioned option was already enabled so I had to disable it and then to enable both options and it helped.

Comment: Worked for my Huawei Honor 8 Lite

Comment: This actually fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: +1, cheers mate,after hours of scavenging the net for over an hour because of this one silly issues, yours did the work in mere seconds.

Comment: Your solution worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 10):

My device is Honor 9lite and I faced this issue after sometime of using debug mode.

You just have to follow these steps:

1. after connecting android device and pc/laptop via usb cable, just enable "transfer files" option.
2. then enable debugging option in developer option menu.
3. a message will be prompted like a certification and just allow that for your device as always.

There you go! It worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me in Huawei Nova 2i

Comment: Worked for me on Huawei P30 Pro

Comment: Worked for me on Huawei P20 lite

Answer (score 4):

Restoring the default settings in developer options worked  for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, none of the previous answers worked (I always got a `unrecognized driver` error). I just used a new cable and it instantly got detected and installed the correct drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting all settings and then enabling USB Debugging worked for me on Huawei MediaPad T5

Comment: This must be a comment rather as a separate answer.

Answer (score -1):

> Restore default setting

in developer options work for me