# Intune company portal causes usb debugging to automatically switch off

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy, usb-debugging

I recently installed [Microsoft Intune company portal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.windowsintune.companyportal) on my Samsung galaxy note 10+ for work. Unfortunately doing so resulted in the following change to my usb debugging settings: ["Block - Prevent devices from using the USB debugging feature"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/protect/compliance-policy-create-android-for-work). Once I discovered this, I fully uninstalled and unerolled from Intune company portal, however the usb debugging block remains. I did notice that I can toggle on and use usb debugging for 2-4 minutes after rebooting my phone, but after that, the switch instantly goes back to off when I try to enable it. I've tried resetting my phone settings, reenabling developer options and then trying to turn on usb debugging, but the setting still behaves the same. I've also tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496745/usb-debugging-option-on-my-android-keeps-turning-off/54040795#54040795) but the setting remains disabled. Any help undoing what company portal did to my phone would be massively appreciated.

Note:
I already disabled/uninstalled several apps potentially related to the issue via adb shell commands during the first few minutes after rebooting. If I knew which lingering app was responsible for enforcing the usb debugging block, I think uninstalling it would fix the issue. I've disabled several so far with no effect. Hoping to avoid factory reset.

phone details/bug screen recording:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uyIRKBnrpW4RH5hmlKJ2mAOMmJXt8j5d?usp=sharing

Comment: clearUserRestriction DISALLOW_DEBUGGING_FEATURES
Apparently, the block may be enforced via devicepolicymanager after each restart: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager#DISALLOW_DEBUGGING_FEATURES

Comment: maybe something like:
adb shell pm set-user-restriction --user 0 no_debugging_features 0